# Docker containers monitoring system using SNMP

Tags: docker, monitoring, snmp

Can anyone tell me if it is a good idea to monitor Docker containers using SNMP? I mean, I'm thinking at installing SNMP agent on each container and collect data throug a Flink/Kafka stream, but I don't know if it's ok to proceed in this way like installing SNMP agent on each container or not.

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of metrics are you collecting? Can it be collected by just running one agent per instance?

Comment: I want to get metrics like cpu core consumption, ram memory consumption etc

Answer (score 2):

There are docker APIs which many tools use to collect this info. You do not need to install anything inside the containers for these basic metrics. The most popular open source tool for this is Prometheus, but there are dozens of commercial tools which use the same method.

https://docs.docker.com/config/thirdparty/prometheus/#configure-docker

Comment: Yeah, I've already used Prometheus inside Docker containers. But I want to develop something based on SNMP. I already know about many tools that are used in production, but I want to develop a new and custom one.

Comment: With Docker, you'll want to keep images small, and adding a bunch of SNMP programs in addition to running snmpd in each container seems like overkill. Most of the Docker collection programs run at the host versus containers. On a large system, you could run hundreds of containers, which means hundreds of snmpd processes. You may want to look at collectd and the fact that it runs on the host and monitors all the containers (if you want to push data) ex: https://signalfx.com/blog/monitoring-docker-containers-take-get-started/

Comment: Yeah, I read a lot about snmp these days and I think that putting snmpd in each Docker container will kill all my system. Thx!

Comment: SNMP is getting outdated by the day, with web services being easier to scale and secure that's been the future path for a while now. I doubt snmpd would use a lot of memory or resources, but it's yet another vector to get into a container.